# Category name (title) translation issue in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, localisation

I have 2 store views (english and another language) in one of my Magento 2 projects.

The problem I'm facing is that one of the categories has the name "Role", which is also an English word.

So when I visit the `category view` page the category title gets translated to the other language's equivalent of the word "Role".

Shouldn't page/category headings be non-translatable through the built-in CSV translation mechanism that Magento provides?

I mean they already are translatable through the Admin store view functionality...

In any case, I've tracked this down to `Magento_Theme::html/title.phtml` and the function `getPageHeading()` in `module-theme/Block/Html/Title.php`

```
public function getPageHeading()
    {
        if (!empty($this->pageTitle)) {
            return __($this->pageTitle);
        }
        return __($this->pageConfig->getTitle()->getShortHeading());
    }
```

Is it possible to disable the translation via `catalog_category_view.xml` with a `referenceBlock name="page.main.title"`?

The only solution I can think of atm is to remove the `page.main.title` block from `category view` pages and add the non-translated title in `Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml`.

**EDIT**

I fixed this temporarily by removing the `page.main.title` block and inserting this to `list.phtml`:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');

if ($category) { ?>
    <h1><?php echo $category->getName(); ?></h1>
<?php } ?>
```

But this isn't the best solution...

Seems like a Magento 2.2. bug to me.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You can achieve this by edit the category storewise and add the category name according to store language

Comment: @PurushotamSharma If I understand you correctly, you mean through the Admin? The categories are already properly named (translated) there. The problem happens only on the frontend - on the category view page of the category "Role" - which gets translated, because "Role" is also an english word and is translated in CSV.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable / disable title translations in theme configuration:

`Content -> Design -> Configuration -> Header -> Translate title (yes/no)`

This option is available in **Magento 2.4.x** but not in the **2.3** line

Comment: Thanks, you made my day!!